Index exceeds number of array elements during KNN
This code should (in theory) do KNN for any given dataset, but for any k > 1 i get Index exceeds number of array elements
%Inputs and other
Dataset = @iris_dataset;
[inputs, targets] = Dataset();
fprintf('Dataset: %s.\n', func2str(Dataset));
[N, I] = size(inputs); 
fprintf('Число элементов N: %i; число атрибутов I: %i.\n', N, I);
M = size(targets, 1); fprintf('Число классов M: %i.\n', M);

%dist
dist = @(arr, v) sqrt(sum(abs(arr - v(:, ones(1, size(arr, 2)))).^2));

%test\train sets
X_train = inputs(1:1, :);
Y_train = targets(1:60);
X_test = inputs(2:end, :);
Y_test = targets(61:end);

%number of neighbours
k = 2;

%FUnk
Y_pred = zeros(size(Y_test));
for i = 1:size(X_test, 1)
    distances = dist(X_train, X_test(i, :));
    [~, iMin] = sort(distances);
    nearest_neighbors = iMin(i:k);
    classes = Y_train(nearest_neighbors);
    Y_pred(i) = mode(classes);
end

% accuracy
accuracy = sum(Y_pred == Y_test) / numel(Y_test);
disp(['Точність похибок: ', num2str(accuracy)]);

The only strings of code in the textbook provided is this
Dataset = @iris_dataset;
[inputs, targets] = Dataset();
fprintf('Dataset: %s.\n', func2str(Dataset));
[N, I] = size(inputs); 
fprintf('Число элементов N: %i; число атрибутов I: %i.\n', N, I);
M = size(targets, 1); fprintf('Число классов M: %i.\n', M);

Please could you advise why I see the error?
P.S after editing the train and test data allocation i can get K>1 but not more then 4 and it only correctly predicts first k points, filling the rest with NaN
% data*vector
inputs = inputs';
targets = vec2ind(targets)';

%dist
dist = @(arr, v) sqrt(sum(abs(arr - v(:, ones(1, size(arr, 2)))).^2));

%test\train sets
cv = cvpartition(targets, 'HoldOut', 0.5);
X_train = inputs(training(cv), :);
Y_train = targets(training(cv));
X_test = inputs(test(cv), :);
Y_test = targets(test(cv));

I dont inderstand what the data*vector does, i just copied it from chatgpt

Did you run your code under the debugger? It lets you see the result of each line. Look closely at what distances contains, I expect that code does something different than what you imagine.

@CrisLuengo To be honest i dont understand what any of this does). A guy who helped me write the dist function told me that i should call it in like this. As far as i understand the math behind this thing, it returns the indexes of the closest elements K.

I wrote it in description, but mods deleted it, i am a radiotech egineer, not a AI specialist, i dont understand anything at all in this theme. Thanks university who decided that replacing additional course security systems with image identification course is a good idea.

I just dont understand, the textbook doesnt contain anything beyond cryptic formulas without explanation. The lessons were for the guys who actually studied the subject from other groups for years, and most of what teaches said was things like "we have studied it before".

''
% data*vector
inputs = inputs';
targets = vec2ind(targets)';
%test\train sets
cv = cvpartition(targets, 'HoldOut', 0.2);
X_train = inputs(training(cv), :);
Y_train = targets(training(cv));
X_test = inputs(test(cv), :);
Y_test = targets(test(cv));
''
Rewrote the data stuff like this and started getting some results, but now the accuracy is no more then 25%

For some reason i dont yet understand, with the data stuff from above i get exactly k right predictions, and after k(which cant exceed 4) i get only NaN

I cant even edit my own post. after moderator edited it, it shows as it has a problem with unmarked code, even while all code is marked, thanks Wolfie

Please don't edit the question to post an answer, don't put in "SOLVED" or similar in the title. Instead, write an answer below in the answer box (as you've already done) and accept that answer, see "What should I do when someone answers my question?". (But do add some more text to your answer to explain the code, code-only answers are not great).

% Грузим датасет(dataset load)
Dataset = @iris_dataset;
[inputs, targets] = Dataset();
%FOR SIMPLECLASS OFFSET
%t = logical(targets);
%inputs(:,t(4,:)) = inputs(:,t(4,:)) - 0.25;
fprintf('Dataset: %s.\n', func2str(Dataset));
[N, I] = size(inputs);
fprintf('Число элементов N: %i; число атрибутов I: %i.\n', N, I);
M = size(targets, 1);
fprintf('Число классов M: %i.\n', M);

% data transform to make it usable
inputs = inputs';
targets = vec2ind(targets)';

% here i split data by factor of 0.25, anything smaller then 1 works
cv = cvpartition(targets, 'HoldOut', 0.25);
X_train = inputs(training(cv), :);
Y_train = targets(training(cv));
X_test = inputs(test(cv), :);
Y_test = targets(test(cv));

% neighbour number
k = 3;

% here we start funktion
Y_pred = knn_predict(X_train, Y_train, X_test, k);

% accuracy
accuracy = sum(Y_pred == Y_test) / length(Y_test);
fprintf('Точность: %.2f%%\n', accuracy * 100);

% weighted funk
Y_pred = weighted_knn_predict(X_train, Y_train, X_test, k);

% точность читаем
accuracy = sum(Y_pred == Y_test) / length(Y_test);
fprintf('Точность: %.2f%%\n', accuracy * 100);

% distance calc funktion
function dist = euclidean_distance(x1, x2)
    dist = sqrt(sum((x1 - x2).^2, 2));
end

% Функция КНН KNN 
function predictions = knn_predict(X_train, Y_train, X_test, k)
    num_test = size(X_test, 1);
    predictions = zeros(num_test, 1);
    
    for i = 1:num_test
        distances = euclidean_distance(X_train, X_test(i, :));
        [ ~ , idx] = sort(distances);
        nearest_labels = Y_train(idx(1:k));
        predictions(i) = mode(nearest_labels);
    end
end

% Weighted 
function predictions = weighted_knn_predict(X_train, Y_train, X_test, k)
    num_test = size(X_test, 1);
    predictions = zeros(num_test, 1);
    
    for i = 1:num_test
        distances = euclidean_distance(X_train, X_test(i, :));
        [sorted_distances, idx] = sort(distances);
        nearest_labels = Y_train(idx(1:k));
        % Calculate weights based on inverse distances
        weights = 1 ./ sorted_distances(1:k);
        % Weighted majority voting
        weighted_votes = accumarray(nearest_labels, weights);
        % Find the label with the highest weighted votes
        [~, max_index] = max(weighted_votes);
        predictions(i) = max_index;
    end
end


Is this just an update of your code or is the problem fixed? If it's fixed, can you clarify what change in the two new functions fixed the problem?
